# Question about lisp Lambda functions from an example in Land of Lisp

Tags: lambda, lisp, land-of-lisp

I'm not quite understanding lambda functions. Here is an example function from the book Land of Lisp:

```
(defun edges->dot (edges)
  (mapc (lambda (node)
          (mapc (lambda (edge)
                  (fresh-line)
                  (princ (dot-name (car node)))
                  (princ "->")
                  (princ (dot-name (car edge)))
                  (princ "[label=\"")
                  (princ (dot-label (cdr edge)))
                  (princ "\"];"))
                (cdr node)))
        edges))
```

Let's just look at the inner part here for now:

```
(mapc (lambda (edge)
        (fresh-line)
        (princ (dot-name (car node)))
        (princ "->")
        (princ (dot-name (car edge)))
        (princ "[label=\"")
        (princ (dot-label (cdr edge)))
        (princ "\"];"))
      (cdr node)))
```

I understand that the function `mapc` takes two arguments, a function and a list. I also understand that by using `lambda (node)` I am passing an anonymous function that takes one argument (`node`) as the first argument to `mapc`, and that `(cdr node)` will be used as the second argument to `mapc`. At least I think that's what's going on!

What I don't understand is where my anonymous function gets the value for `edge` in `(lambda (edge)`. I would appreciate it if someone could please explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `edge` argument comes from the items in `(cdr node)`. Your inner lambda will be called once for each element in `(cdr node)`.

Try this for example:

```
(mapc #'princ '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Or, with a literal lambda:

```
(mapc #'(lambda (x)
          (princ x)
          (terpri))
      '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Comment: Okay, so would it be correct to say that the first argument of mapc must be a function of only one argument?

Comment: @MikeJerome: Correct, if you're passing in one list. In general, your function takes as many arguments as lists you're passing in.